# Unrecognized option: -modulepath

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, module-path

Is anyone else having this issue when they run the module it complains about this in java 9 mac version?

**Below is the issue!**

```
Unrecognized option: -modulepath
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

How to reproduce ?
I am doing this [example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/04/javafx-helloworld-using-java-9s-project-jigsaw-60-seconds.html). The last step is to run the module using below command. That's when i see the issue.

```
java -modulepath mods -m com.mycompany.helloworld/com.mycompany.helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Here is some background information.
. I started playing with java 9 (mac version).

```
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+138)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+138, mixed mode)
```

I can not even uninstall the java 9 properly. But, I will solve that later.

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Not at my computer but try `--module-path` - I believe there was a standardisation effort for Unix like options.

Answer (score 3):

As Joop Eggen have said, there is an effort in the JDK to standardize the command-line options and use the GNU-style `--starting-with-double-dash-and-dash-separated-long-options`. So yes, `--module-path` is what you're looking for.

For the reference:

- The module system options were renamed in build 132, issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136930
- Code review thread with the options summary: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2016-August/009025.html.
- Here is the JEP that gives the guidelines for the newly added options and tools: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/293